# Problems with parsing products from amazon

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I wanted to parse amazon products, but I got this traceback. I cant't figure out why it is happening. I think it may happened because the site doesn't want me to do this.

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "c:\Users\grafity\Desktop\main.py", line 42, in

```
main()
```

File "c:\Users\grafity\Desktop\main.py", line 31, in main

```
products = get_products(search_url)

           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

File "c:\Users\grafity\Desktop\main.py", line 14, in get_products

```
response.raise_for_status()
```

File "C:\Users\grafity\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\requests\models.py", line 1021, in raise_for_status

```
raise HTTPError(http_error_msg, response=self)
```

requests.exceptions.HTTPError: 503 Server Error: Service Unavailable for url:
https://www.amazon.ca/s?k=RTX+3070ti

Edited: I spent some time and somehow made it work but it is very inconsistent. Sometimes it parses the cards well, sometimes values are half Null and, generally, all of the values are Null. How can i make ,y program more consistent and relieble. Here is some sample output:

{"img": null, "name": null, "price": null, "url": null}, {"img": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/71vWKkde2yL.*AC_UY218*.jpg", "name": null, "price": null, "url": "/sspa/click?ie=UTF8&spc=MToyNjUzMzM1MzIwODAzNjE5OjE2OTQ1MzczOTE6c3BfYXRmOjMwMDAwMTUzMzIyNDgwMjo6MDo6&url=%2FPNY-GeForce-Uprising-Triple-Graphics%2Fdp%2FB0C1HVL3BD%2Fref%3Dsr_1_1_sspa%3Fkeywords%3DRTX%2B3070ti%26qid%3D1694537391%26sr%3D8-1-spons%26sp_csd%3Dd2lkZ2V0TmFtZT1zcF9hdGY%26psc%3D1"}, {"img": "https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/81d0pk3xOiS.*AC_UY218*.jpg", "name": null, "price": 843.0, "url": "/MSI-Gaming-RTX-3070-Trio/dp/B096HJC18P/ref=sr_1_2?keywords=RTX+3070ti&qid=1694537391&sr=8-2"}

Comment: It means the server isn't available. Maybe you can repeat the request after a while.

Comment: For more information, I'd recommend checking out [HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status).

Comment: For more information, check out [HTTP response status codes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status) on MDN.

Comment: they don't like bots. even if you don't get error, you'll just get captcha....you could give selenium a try though

Answer (score 0):

> *How can i make my program more consistent and reliable.*

You could run the scraper multiple times [with some time in between in case you get blocked] and update with only non-null values, or [as suggested in my comment] try selenium because that will likely give more consistent and reliable results.

Comment: i am already using Selenium and trying to connect mulptiple times with some intervals and generally get the data after 2 or 3 retries (and this is one of the reasons i called my program inconsistent) and i added the check for some of the value i.e. if the product name is Null i parse it from alt inside the image tag etc. but it is not good enough still